# How to avoid duplicate values in non-unique fields? SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005, unique-constraint

I have created two tables using Entity Framework, `Employer` and `Department`.

[Employer and Departments tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Pvx.png)

```
public class Employer
{
       [key]
       public int Emp_id {get; set;}
       public string Emp_Name {get; set;}
}

public class Department
{
       [key]
       public int Dep_id {get; set;}
       public string Dep_Name {get; set;}
       public Employer Employer_EmployerId {get; set;}
}
```

Any employer may have a department named "MainOffice", but one particular employer can have only one "MainOffice".

So I can't pose a unique constraint on Dep_Name in the Department table.

How can I implement using data annotations so that if an employer already has a Department named "MainOffice", a new one with the same name cannot be inserted for that particular Employer?

How can one implement it in Entity Framework, code-first?

Comment: The entity model (and tables) looks wrong. A classical `Employee` and `Department` with unique name constrains + many-to-many via implicit junction table sounds more appropriate to me.

Comment: I found that unique constraints don't work too well in EF. however, if you want this unique behavior in the one-to-many relationship, a Unique index on the columns Employer_EmployerId and Dep_Name (or Dep_Function, should you introduce it) sounds reasonable.